# Give tabBar 2 different colors in iOS?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, background-color, uitabbar

I am working on a new iPad version of my app which is using a tabBar. I want to add a containerView to the left (the black area) in all my tabBar-Views UI:

[image]

Since container views can't overlap the tabBar (I guess?) the UI will look weird in the left corner of the tabBar. The goal / aim is to accomplish something like Spotifys iPad UI but with a native tabBar in the app:
[image]

So is it possible to color the tabBar UI's left corner? Like 100 width to the left with another color? If so, how? Or maybe another trick?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If i did not understand wrong, the thing you need is a side menu. You may have a look at https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu

Comment: I already have a sidemenu for my iPhone version. I want a static menu only for iPad and not use the side menu

Comment: Well, you may have a UIViewController that you place the menu on the left side and a container for the content. Then, as users will touch menu buttons, you may update the content for container.